# connect to the mysql database with jdbc connector in intellij13

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

when i have to connect to mysql with jdbc an error occure in this code line:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
/server1","root","admin");
```

the error is:

```
C:\jdk\bin\java -Didea.launcher.port=7539 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\IntelliJ IDEA 
13.0.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\jdk\jre\lib\i18n.jar;C:\jdk\jre
\lib\jaws.jar;C:\jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\jdk\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Users\Kamyar
\Desktop\chatjava\untitled3\out\production\untitled3;C:\Users\Kamyar\Desktop\MYjdbc
\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar;C:\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" 
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain ccc

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Savepoint
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:517)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:177)
at ccc.main(ccc.java:17)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Exception in thread "main" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

how can i do to resolve the problem?
thanks...

Comment: i added this class before create the connection...

Comment: @KamyarSafari which version java are u using ?

Comment: i use mysql-java-connector- 5.1.6

Comment: `java.sql.SavePoint` was added in Java 1.4, you are either using an older java version, or your classpath is severely broken with a Java `rt.jar` of an older version or something like that.

Comment: He asked for the Java version, not the MySQL Connector/J version. Given that in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222079/connecting-to-database-in-the-intellij-13) you used Connector/J 5.1.26 I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Delete your current JDK install (which is probably Java 1.3 or older!) and install Java 7 instead.